# How to monitor the tap event of items under tabbarcontroller->More?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using a `UITabbarController`, and added 10 `UINavigationController` into the subviews, so, some of the `UINavigationController`s would be in "More" controller.

The problem is, delegate method `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` doesn't apply to the `UINavigationController`s in "More".

Now, I want to do something (show a modal view controller) when the items in "More" is tapped. What should I do?

Appreciate for any tips.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got following code from other forum, but didn't get chance to give it a shot.

```
NSArray *views = [tabBarController.view subviews];
for(id v in views){
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]){
        [(UITabBar *)v setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```